# How to find coordinates on a straight line from one point at a particular distance

Tags: geometry

Let say we have a $2$D coordinate and a circle, the center is at origin and a straight line passes through the circle.

Let one coordinate is $(-3,3)$ and other we have to find the other coordinates$(x,y)$, where a straight line cuts the opposite side of coordinate$(-3,3)$. the straight line passes through the origin.

According to the above coordinates, the answer will be $(3,-3)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you please show some of the work that led you to believe the answer is $(3,-3)$? Showing your work is a good habit to get into on this site.

Comment: This is unclear to me. Perhaps rephrasing, giving different names to different things, and breaking this long sentence into several simple ones would help.

Comment: Sorry the equation of line is x=y.

Comment: Don't you mean $x=-y?$

Comment: Are you asking whether your answer is correct?  Why are you unsure?

Comment: I just wanted the mathematical way or formula for all straightlines

Comment: I don't see any problem with the logic. I could 'see' it as it was explained how the circle was centered on the origin with a radius of 3, and the other intersection of the line with the circle would be 3,-3.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the center of the circle is at origin. Now you can use the parametric form of the coordinates of a point on a straight line. Which tells the coordinates of two points on a straight line(in our case: the diameter under consideration) and a given point. Now we can use :
Coordinates (x±rcosA,y±rsinA) where r is the radius of the circle.
This is the best way to know it, according to me.